# Not able to clear Google colab disk space

Tags: google-colaboratory, diskspace

I have been using Google colab for quite sometime. Recently I noticed that 43 GB of disk space is already occupied. Even if I change runtime to TPU 43 GB out of 107 GB remains occupied. I tried factory reset runtime but it doesn't work. Even if I use Google colab from another Google account still 43 GB of disk space is occupied. How to clear the disk space ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's some amount of space that's used by the base operating system and libraries. You won't be able to trim this value very much by deleting files since most will be required for normal operation.

If you need a larger disk, consider [Colab Pro](https://colab.research.google.com/signup), which has 2x the disk space.